# Replacing occurrence of a word in child element using string search and replace

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a javascript function that suppose to replace classnames and inner text of a child element. Roughly relevant section of my page look like this :

```
<a class="c1 c2"> 
<i _ngcontent-qde-3="" class="material-icons rightIcon" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="chevron_left">chevron_left</i>    
</a>
```

I want to replace all occurrence of chevron_left with chevron_right. This is my javascript code :

```
    var innerHTML = sidenav_chevron.innerHTML;                      
    sidenav_chevron.innerHTML = innerHTML.replace("chevron_left", "chevron_right");
```

The above code, however, only replace value of ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l to chevron_right.Not the inner text of "i" tag. The result looks like :

```
<a class="c1 c2"> 
   <i _ngcontent-qde-3="" class="material-icons rightIcon" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="chevron_right">chevron_left</i>    
</a>
```

Why is string replace function only replaces attribute value instead of all occurrences? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got it all working. Thanks to the poster who answered my question and then deleted it(for some reason). So, it uses matching pattern instead of string. So, now, working version looks like this :

```
 sidenav_chevron.innerHTML = sidenav_chevron.innerHTML.replace(/chevron_left/g, "chevron_right");
```